# Most cited contract law review article?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, legal-research, law-review

What is the most cited Legal review article about contract law on a federal level in the past ten years?

"cited" in this sentence, refers to citations of the article in other published works (not obscure references in a blog post).

Comment: The contract law profs blog rates articles weekly. https://lawprofessors.typepad.com/contractsprof_blog

Comment: "Friedrich Kessler, Contracts of#Adhesion Some Thoughts about Freedom of
Contract, 43 COLUM. L. REV. 629 (1943)." https://repository.law.umich.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1084&context=mlr See https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3022597

Comment: Recent list Dec 2018 "1. 
Regulating Blockchain: Techno-Social and Legal Challenges - An Introduction
Philipp Hacker, Ioannis Lianos, Georgios Dimitropoulos and Stefan Eich
Humboldt University of Berlin, University College London - Faculty of Laws, Hamad Bin Khalifa University and Princeton Society of Fellows" https://lawprofessors.typepad.com/contractsprof_blog/2018/12/the-periodic-table-of-top-ten-ssrn-contracts-commercial-law-downloads-december-18-2018-.html